# Is Energy Usage Level shown with 4th generation iPodTouch?

Tags: ios, instruments, energy

In the Instruments Documentation, when talking about Energy Usage Level, it is said:

*Note: The Energy Usage instrument is currently supported in the iPhone 3GS and the third-generation iPod touch.*

I suppose this Note only talks about 3rd Generation because when it was written this was the newest generation, but I have been trying to know the Energy Usage Level with a 4th generation iPod Touch for a long time and I haven't got it (I asked for this problem in this question: [Instruments doesn't show Energy Usage Level: it is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646238/instruments-doesnt-show-energy-usage-level-it-is-empty)) so I think perhaps this note is also currently true. 
I think it is strange that Note said "IN third generation" instead of "FROM third generation".

So the question is: Is the Energy Usage Level shown with 4rd generation too or not?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It works on a iPhone 4 for me.

I also took a while to figure it out, how it works.
You can't get the energy level while the device is connected to power.
You need to unplug it, do run your tests, plug it in and import the collected data.

This way it at least worked for me.

Comment: I did it and I couldn't get it. When do you exactly put on/off the Logging option in Settings?

Comment: Settings.app -> Developer -> Turn 'Logging' switch to ON

Comment: I mean, do you put on/off this when the iPhone is plugged or when it isn't? or doesn't it matter? If I only follow the Apple's documentation steps the memory usage level isn't shown with my iPodTouch 4th Gen. :(