# NSTimer and battery charge on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using lots of timer in my app ..will it be reduce my battery . ? 
If yes how can i program with effective energy management .?

Thanks

Comment: Every process running on iOS will take power, there is nothing with `NSTimer`. When you are doing anything or timer is running it'll take power (power for processor)

Comment: You really shouldn't be worrying about using `NSTimer`s in your app. There are far more CPU-intensive tasks that are performed by even standard utility apps like Mail, so this won't have a noticeable impact on battery life.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

App process is divided into 3 main categories: **on-die**, **on-chip**, and **off-chip**.

**On-Die** : Process that runs within Processor

**On-Chip** : Process that runs in Chip, especially RAM

**Off-Chip** : Process that runs using other hardware, such as Bluetooth, Modem, Storage, etc

**Battery Consumption** : On-Die < On-Chip < Off-Chip

For `NSTimer`, it will run in **On-Die** & **On-Chip**, that will spend rather small amount of battery. Depends on what is running in each timer loop, battery usage varies.

welcome to discuss.

Answer (score 2):

`NSTimer` is just a method under many others in iOS to schedule a task for later execution. As a rule of thumb, which method you choose to schedule a task has practically no effect on your battery consumption but how often you schedule your task and what you do in your task has.

To optimize battery consumption with periodically scheduled tasks you should keep in mind:

- Don't schedule more often than necessary
- Do as little as possible in each run, especially for tasks that get executed frequently

Answer (score 1):

You can profile your app in instrument's power consumption to zero-in the op that sucks your battery. There is a post on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715148/iphone-4-profile-power-consumption-with-instruments). [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/EnergyUsageInstrument/EnergyUsageInstrument.html) to apple ref doc.